# JavaScript, Node.JS : unable to read and write a text file (async, await problem)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a function that edits a `PHP` file using `fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile`, but the `PHP` file stays the same. However, when I run the logic at the main function of the `node.js` file, it does edit the `PHP` file. The following is the code of my function.

```
create_page = async (event) => {
    // edits password.php
    const pwd_pg_loc = '/password.php'

    fs.readFile(pwd_pg_loc, 'utf8', async function (err, data) {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        const result = await data.replace('$password = \`\`;', '$password= \'1234\';')
        fs.writeFile(pwd_pg_loc, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err)
        })
    })
})
```

I think I have `async`, `await` problems here. Any advise is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> async function (err, data)

This looks like you're combining old-school callback semantics `(err, data)` with Promise semantics.

Probably it should be something like:

```js
const data = await fs.readFile(pwd_pg_loc, 'utf8')
```

Also:

```
const result = await data.replace(...
```

There's no need for `await` here as `data.replace` is synchronous.

Comment: I get the following error.
```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received 'utf8'```
I guess 'utf8' should not be entered as an input.

Comment: I edited ```readFile``` to ```readFileSync``` and it works now. Thanks!